# F# how to deal with this recursive mutal class method

Tags: f#

I have the following piece of code where I need to call on my own class that I reference via a reference on a mutual class(hope that makes sense, if not the code sample explains it better).

Unfortunately it does work because I get the "Lookup on object of indeterminate type prior to..." error on the 'x.Connections.[0].Dest.Func' part.

Can anyone think of a way to fix this, possibly I will have to just go for quite a different approach?

```
type Node() =
    member x.Connections = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Connection>()
    member x.Connect other = x.Connections.Add(Connection(x, other))
    member x.Func i : unit = x.Connections.[0].Dest.Func i
and Connection(source : Node, dest : Node) =
    member val Source = source
    member val Dest = dest
```

Ignore the fact that calling the Func method on Node serves no purpose, I've simplified this from the real code to try to just show what causes the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also just add a type annotation to `Dest`, which appears to be the critical symbol that throws the type inference algorithm into a loop:

```
type Node() =
    member x.Connections = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Connection>()
    member x.Connect other = x.Connections.Add(Connection(x, other))    
    member x.Func i : unit = x.Connections.[0].Dest.Func i                             
and Connection(source : Node, dest : Node) =
    member val Source = source
    member val Dest : Node = dest
```

Comment: Yes, this actually works as well. I'm surprised that the compiler needs the hint given it should be able to infer it easily, it almost looks like a bug in the compiler...

Answer (score 3):

Try declaring that method at the end:

```
type Node() =
    member x.Connections = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Connection>()
    member x.Connect other = x.Connections.Add(Connection(x, other))

and Connection(source : Node, dest : Node) =
    member val Source = source
    member val Dest = dest

type Node with
    member x.Func i : unit = x.Connections.[0].Dest.Func i
```

or may be better swap the order of the types:

```
type Connection(source : Node, dest : Node) =
    member val Source = source
    member val Dest = dest
and Node() =
    member x.Connections = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Connection>()
    member x.Connect other = x.Connections.Add(Connection(x, other))
    member x.Func i : unit = x.Connections.[0].Dest.Func i
```

Comment: Thank you so much, two great solutions. The 2nd one doesn't quite work for my real world case, but the first one is perfect.

Comment: Yes, that will only work for this piece of code, that's why I wrote it as a second option.